# failing to remove http:// url from my string with regex

Tags: php, regex, string, url, preg-replace

my string is: `Visit Our Website: http://website.com/String continue..` (it's not an error - url ends and String continue begins without space!)

i need to remove url from the string and leave *String continue*

my code is `echo $s = preg_replace('/([\b](?=http:\/\/)[\S]+])/', '', $s);` It fails of course..

who knows the right answer?

**SOLVED IT**:  `$s = preg_replace('#\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))#', '', $s);`

Answer (score 2):

Use can you [`str_split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

```
$string_parts = str_split($url, '/');
var_dump($string_parts);
```

Everything after `website.com/` should be in `$string_parts[3]`

Comment: The point of my answer was to be more readable.  Having a complicated regex doesn't necessarily make the code better than a solution that does not.

Comment: don't search simple ways!) nevertheless genius is the ability to reduce the complicated to the simple. Why have you deleted my note about monkey? isn't you who voted -1 for me Ж=(

Comment: you'd better give me a SUPER MASTER badge ))) ok. thk's for good job&dialog)

Answer (score 0):

`String` can be a valid part of the URL. Imagine if I typed the url of this page:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232849/failing-to-remove-http-url-from-my-string-with-regex
```

Your attempt to remove the URL would either leave

```
questions/9232849/failing-to-remove-http-url-from-my-string-with-regex
```

or

```
failing-to-remove-http-url-from-my-string-with-regex
```

in your text.

Unfortunately there is no reliable way to remove the URL in the way you are suggesting here.